# wrong result Collectors.groupingBy in java

Tags: java, arrays, collectors

i have file.txt i would to group data by ip i'm using Collectors.groupingBy

file data

> ```
> 333.000.000,Newyork,50
> 200.000.000,china,200
> 333.000.000,brazil,150
> 444.000.000,japon,40
> 200.000.000,icland,400
> ```

i use Collectors.groupingBy to group data so i need to show result like this :

```
333.000.000=[Newyork,brazil]
200.000.000=[china,icland]
444.000.000=[japon]
```

the probelme is show result like this :

```
333.000.000=[class_ip@5b6f7412,class_ip@8b6f7412]
200.000.000=[class_ip@312b1dae,class_ip@6b7f7412]
444.000.000=[class_ip@7530d0]
```

My code

```
class class_ip{
    private String ip;
    private String title;
    public class_ip(String ip,String title) {
        this.ip = ip;        
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getIP() {return ip;}
    public String getTitle() {return title;}

    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title;}
    public void setIP(String ip) { this.ip = ip;}

    public String getAll() {
        return ip+","+title;
    }
} 

     List<class_ip> array_ip = new ArrayList<>();

    // read data from file
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                array_ip.add(new class_ip(ip,title));
    }

   Map<String,List<class_ip>> groupByIP = new HashMap<>();
   groupByIP =array_ip.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(class_ip::getIP)); 

   System.out.println(groupByIP);
```

Comment: Add a toString method to your class_ip to render it the way you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the titles instead of the `class_ip` instances, use `Collectors.mapping` and generate a `Map<String,List<String>>`:

```
Map<String,List<String>> groupByIP = 
    array_ip.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(class_ip::getIP,
                                           Collectors.mapping(class_ip::getTitle,
                                                              Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `class_ip@312b1dae` is retured by the default [`Object#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), you need override it in `class_ip`, for example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getTitle();
}
```